# what does event (A and B) actually stand for?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have two events, say, A,B then sometimes we use
`P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B)` and
`P(A and B) = P(A) x P(B)`
while some other times we use
`P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)`
I am confused about when to use former form and when to use later, where comes the concept of independent event in all this, plz explain with some analogy.

Answer (score 1):

P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) is true **if the events A and B are *mutually exclusive*** (or if the sets A and B are *disjoint*), that is $A \cap B = \emptyset$. It is one of the **Kolmogorov axioms of probability**.

See more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms

Example:

Event A: Roll a fair die, and get a 6.
Event B: Roll a fair die, and get a 5.

If we want to compute $P(A \cup B)$, we can note that A and B are mutually exclusive and thus use the formula P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) = 1/6 + 1/6 = 1/3

**P(A and B) = P(A) x P(B) is true if and only if A and B are independent.** Some books use this as the **definition of independence**. Some books use a different definition of independence and then arrive at the statement as a theorem.

See more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#Two_events

Example:

Event A: Roll a fair die, and get a 6.
Event B: Flip a fair coin, and get heads.

If we want to compute P(A and B) and if we are given that A and B are independent (or if we deduce it somehow from other information), we can use the formula P(A and B) = P(A) x P(B) = (1/6)(1/2) = 1/12

P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) is the **addition law of probability**. It can be deduced from the Kolmogorov axioms.

See more: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Addition_Law_of_Probability#Proof_2

Example:

Event A: Roll a fair die, and get a 4 or 5.
Event B: Roll a fair die, and get a 5 or 6.

Observe that

P(A or B) = 3/6
P(A) = 2/6
P(B) = 2/6
P(A and B) = 1/6

Note that the formula P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B) holds.

Answer (score 0):

Example of **disjoint** events:

- Let A be an event of choosing the number $2$ or $3$ or $4$ from the range $[1,10]$
- Let B be an event of choosing the number $6$ or $7$ or $8$ from the range $[1,10]$

In this example:

- $\color{blue}{P(A \cap B)=0}$
- $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$

---

Example of **independent** events:

- Let A be an event of choosing a number divisible by $2$ from the range $[1,10]$
- Let B be an event of choosing a number divisible by $3$ from the range $[1,10]$

In this example:

- $\color{blue}{P(A \cap B)=P(A) \times P(B)}$
- $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$

---

Please note:

- $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ in both cases
- The actual unique property of each case is marked blue